# need to switch between class scopes

Tags: php, symfony, scope, doctrine

I have a class (`PersistenceClass`), that takes an array of data (`posts`) and parses that data and puts it into a DB (via doctrine). The field `content` needs to be parsed by a second class (`SyntaxClass`) before it is set into the doctrine entity.

Now the problem is, that the `SyntaxClass` has to set references in the content to other posts (just a link with and ID). So it needs access to the DB, and also needs to search in the persisted but not yet flushed entities from the `PersistenceClass`.

I can inject a doctrine EM into `SyntaxClass` and find my references in DB, although I dont like it very much. But the bigger problem is, how I can access the only persisted, but not flushed entities from the `PersistenceClass` ? I could make an Array of that objects and put it as an parameter to the parser method like:

```
SyntaxClass->parseSyntax($content, $persistedObjects);
```

But that does not look very clean. Aside from that, I dont know if it is somehow possible to search in the data of the persisted objects?

Comment: You can see which entities are persisted but not flushed yet looking at the UnitOfWork `EntityManager#getUnitOfWork()` (from [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#direct-access-to-a-unit-of-work))

Answer (score 1):

Your question is full of sub-question, so, first I'll try to make some things clear.

First, the naming convention you used is a bit abiguos and this not helps, me and also other people that may work on your code in future (maybe you'll grow and need to hire more developers! :P ). So, let's start with some nomenclature.

What you are calling `PersistenceClass` may be something like this:

```
class PersistenceClass
{
    public function parse(array $posts)
    {
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            // 1. Parse $post
            // 2. Parse content with SyntaxClass
            // 3. Persist $post in the database
        }
    }
}
```

The same applies also for `SyntaxClass`: it receives the `$content` and parses it in some ways, then sets the references and then persists.

This is just to set some boundaries.

Now, go to your questions.

> I can inject a doctrine EM into SyntaxClass and find my references in
>   DB, although I dont like it very much.

This is exactly what you have to do! The OOP development works this way.

But, and here come the problems with naming conventions, the way you inject the entity manager depends on the structure of your classes.

A good design should use [services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#what-is-a-service).

So, what currently are `PersistenceClass` and `SyntaxClass` in reality should be called `PersistenceService` and `SyntaxService` (also if I prefere call them `PersistenceManager` and `SyntaxManager`, because in my code I always distinguish between managers and handlers - but this is a convention of mine, so I'll not write more about it here).

Now, another wrong thing that I'm imaging you are doing (only reading your question, I'M IMAGING!): you are instantiating `SyntaxService` (you currently named `SyntaxClass`) from inside `PersistenceService` (your currently named `PersistenceClass`). This is wrong.

If you need a fresh instance of `SyntaxService` for each post, then you should use a factory class (say `SyntaxFactory`), so calling `SyntaxFactory::create()` you'll get a fresh instance of `SyntaxService`. Is the factory itself that injects the entity manager in the newly created `SyntaxClass`.

If you don't need a fresh instance each, time, instead, you'll declare `SyntaxClass` simply as a service and will pass it to `PersistenceService` by injection. Below this last simpler example:

```
# app/config/service.yml
services:
    app.service.persistence:
        class: ...\PersistenceService
        # Pass the SyntaxInstance directly or a factory if you need one
        aguments: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", "@app.service.syntax"]
    app.service.syntax:
        class: ...\SyntaxService
        aguments: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
```

> But the bigger problem is, how I can access the only persisted, but
>   not flushed entities from the PersistenceClass ?

Now the second question: how to search for {persisted + flushed} and {persisted + not flushed} entities?

The problem is that you cannot use the ID as the search parameter as the persisted but not flushed entities doesn't have one before the flushing.

The solution may be to create another service: `SearchReferencesService`. In it you'll inject the entity manager too (as shown before).

So this class has a method `search()` that does the search.

To search for the entities persisted but not flushed, the `UnitOfWork` gives you some interesting methods: `getScheduledEntityInsertions()`, `getScheduledEntityUpdates()`, `getScheduledEntityDeletions()`, `getScheduledCollectionDeletions()` and `getScheduledCollectionUpdates()`.

The array of which you are speaking about is already there: you need to only cycle it and compare object by object, basing the search on fields other than the ID one (as it doesn't exist yet).

Unfortunately, as you didn't provided more details about the nature of your search, it is not possible for me to be more precise about how to do this search, but only tell you you have to search using the unit of work and connecting to the database if `null` results are returned by the first search. Also the order in which you'll do this search (before in the database and then in the unit of work or viceversa) is up to you.

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for the long answer :) First: yes the naming is very simple and ambigous because I just made it up for the question here (I wanted to break down the complexity of the real system). And yes the classes are services. And no, my intention and current flow is not, that the syntax class persists the data. Actually the Syntax class is only a helper and does provide only one public function (`parseString`) that returns the parsed string. Actually I dont like it to connect to DB, but there is no other way now because of the references.

Comment: but the idea to make up a new service for the reference search might be a good one, I will think reconsider that. Because the search for references will be quite complex, I think I will flush all posts first and flag them somehow like "not syntaxed yet"